iOS Auto renewable subscriptions first submission. Apple can't fetch Products and reject the app
I am trying to submit an update that introduces auto renewable subscriptions. Even though I can test and confirm the flow, Apple fails to reproduce the behavior and constantly reject the submission. The state is as follows:

I configured the subscriptions in App Store Connect.
Added IAP as Signing & Capabilities along with .storekit file to test locally.
I retrieve the Products with their IDs matching the ones in App Store Connect using StoreKit Product.products(for:) API.
I can fetch the products to .storekit file using Sync button.
Everything works fine locally.

Then I submit the build and Apple picks up the build for review along with the subscriptions. When this happens, when I sync .storekit file, it doesn't retrieve any product. And apple reports that the subscription build is failing (because of Products not being listed). I understand that they test in the sandbox environment. What I don't understand is how can I verify everything works in that environment myself. Since Products API return an empty list when subscriptions are in "Waiting for Review" or in "In Review" state.
From what I understand, I have to have the subscriptions approved for the build to pass, but the build needs to pass for subscriptions to be approved.
I request support from Apple but they rejected that too. Also they won't respond to emails with any information.
I am quite stuck so would appreciate any help. Thanks!
